# Does only running "BEGIN;" or "START TRANSACTION;" query really start a transaction? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, transactions, information-schema

On **MySQL**, first, I ran `BEGIN;` or `START TRANSACTION;` to start a transaction as shown below:

```
mysql> BEGIN;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Or:

```
mysql> START TRANSACTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Then, I ran the query below to check if the transaction is running but I got nothing as shown below:

```
mysql> SELECT trx_id FROM information_schema.innodb_trx;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

So just after this, I ran the query below to show all the rows of **`person` table**:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM person;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | John |
|  2 | Tom  |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then again, I ran the query below, then now, I could check the transaction is actually running:

```
mysql> SELECT trx_id FROM information_schema.innodb_trx;
+-----------------+
| trx_id          |
+-----------------+
| 284321631771648 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, does only running **`BEGIN;` or `START TRANSACTION;` query** really start a transaction?

Comment: Why not read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) where it's clear it's more complicated than just what you've said. For instance, you need to read and understand autocommit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `start transaction` starts a transaction. Otherwise, that statement would have a very misleading name.

You can check this by trying to do things you cannot do inside a transaction, e.g. [change the isolation level](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-transaction.html):

```
START TRANSACTION; 
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
```

> ERROR 1568 (25001): Transaction characteristics can't be changed while a transaction is in progress

So why don't you see it in the `innodb_trx` table?

Because `innodb_trx` only lists transactions that involve *InnoDB*. Until you e.g. query an InnoDB-table, the InnoDB engine doesn't know about that transaction and doesn't list it, just as shown in your tests. Try changing the table to a MyISAM-table. It will not show up in `innodb_trx` even after you ran a query on it.

A transaction is started on the mysql level, not the [storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-engines.html) level.

For example, the NDB engine also supports transactions and has its own [transaction table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-cluster-excerpt/8.0/en/mysql-cluster-ndbinfo-cluster-transactions.html) where it only shows transactions that involve NDB tables.